# Making udp sockets non-blocking by making the socket Event Driven

Tags: c, windows, sockets, networking, udp

I am trying to make my Socket "Event Based". Following is what i tried:

```
VOID createServerSocket()
{
   WSADATA wsa; 

   //Initialise winsock//
   if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2),&wsa) != 0)
      {

        //"WinSock Initialization FAILED",

      }

   //Create a socket//

  SOCKET newSocketIdentifier;
  SOCKADDR_IN newSocket;

  if((newSocketIdentifier = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_DGRAM , 0 )) == INVALID_SOCKET)
      {                 

        //Socket Creation Failed

      }
   //Socket Created//

   //Prepare the sockaddr_in structure//
  newSocket.sin_family = AF_INET;
  newSocket.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
  newSocket.sin_port = htons(8888);

   //Bind//
   if( bind(newSocketIdentifier ,(struct sockaddr *)&newSocket, sizeof(SOCKADDR_IN)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
      { 
       //Bind Failed
      }

   //Bind Done//

   WSAEVENT NewEvent = WSACreateEvent();
   WSAEventSelect(newSocketIdentifier, NewEvent, FD_READ | FD_WRITE); //made the socket "newSocketIdentifier" event based for events "FD_READ" and FD_WRITE

}
```

I don't know how to proceed further. How shall I check whether any of the desired events had occur? How can I continuously keep checking for these events? Will that be under some while(1) loop?

All the examples I found over the internet are for multiple sockets. However, in my case, I only have a single socket and I want to make it "Event Driven" for Read and Write. Please help me. I am stuck!

Comment: Yes you need to loop continuously to check for events and yes Select is supposed to be used for multiple sockets to be non blocking.

Comment: @shazin : Can you share some example of how to handle these events generated? I am using a single socket not multiple sockets.

Comment: You aren't making anything non-blocking here. You are superimposing multiplexed I/O over blocking I/O. Reads and writes may still block.

Comment: +1 for correctly understanding the thing :)
You're right! I am trying to make my application event based i.e. whenever soomething is ready to be read or written on the socket, an Event is generated and then read and write may block :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to listen for UDP packets coming in, try and use the following code snippet and see.

```
/ Initialize Winsock.
WSADATA wsaData;
int iResult = WSAStartup( MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData );
if ( iResult != NO_ERROR )
    printf("Error at WSAStartup()\n");

// Create a socket.
SOCKET m_socket[1];
m_socket[0] = socket( AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP );

if ( m_socket[0] == INVALID_SOCKET ) {
    printf( "Error at socket(): %ld\n", WSAGetLastError() );
    WSACleanup();
    return;
}

// Bind the socket.
sockaddr_in service[1];

service[0].sin_family = AF_INET;
service[0].sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
service[0].sin_port = htons( 8888 );

if ( bind( m_socket[0], (SOCKADDR*) &service[0], sizeof(service[0]) ) == SOCKET_ERROR ) {
    printf( "bind() failed.\n" );
    closesocket(m_socket[0]);
    return;
}

char data[256];
int bytes, waitRet;

WSAEVENT hEvent = WSACreateEvent();
WSANETWORKEVENTS events;
WSAEventSelect(*m_socket, hEvent, FD_READ | FD_WRITE);
while(1)
{
    waitRet = WSAWaitForMultipleEvents(2, &hEvent, FALSE, WSA_INFINITE, FALSE);
    if(WSAEnumNetworkEvents(*m_socket,hEvent,&events) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        cout << "Error";
    }
    else
    {
        if(events.lNetworkEvents & FD_READ)
        {
            bytes = recv(*m_socket, data, 256, 0);
            cout << data << endl;
        }
    }
}

WSACloseEvent(hEvent);
```

Comment: Ancient history I know but the first parameter for `WSAWaitForMultipleEvents()` should be 1, not 2!